# Replacing a word in Latex?

Tags: spacing, errors, formatting

I have a particular word in my latex document which is encountered around 50 times. And it needs to be changed for different cases.

Like **O/P-1** needs to be replaced with **+5V**
and **O/P-2** needs to be replaced with **+15V.**

In the next case, it could be **O/P-1** as +15V and **O/P-2** as **-15V.**

I want to know with code how is this possible to change all the instances of words in the document

Comment: Hi! Have you tried to define a command in the preamble such as `\newcommand{\OPone}{+5V}`?
(Btw, if you could provide a small example of what you want to achieve your question would be clearer)

Comment: @jschiavon you can't use numbers in command names like this.

Comment: You are right! I just woke up :(! I'm editing it!

Comment: You mention that various cases might apply, or occur. How will LaTeX know which case applies when? E.g., are the cases marked via some conditional?

Answer (score 1):

You should give [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries?lang=en) package a go.

You can use the following to define a word in the preamble(before the `\begin{document}`:

```
\newglossaryentry{word1}{name={O/P-1},description={A word that might have to change later}}
```

Then whenever you need O/P-1 in the text body (between the `\begin{document}` and the `\end{document}`). You use the command `\gls{word1}`.
When you need to change the word, you simply edit the right place in the preamble.